# Javascript - saving and retrieving login credentials to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, forms

Quick inquiry regarding saving and retrieving a user's credentials to an array (which I further intend to save to a text file, but that isn't the issue for the time being).

I have a simple login/register form in place, which seemingly has no overall flaws with it, but I am struggling immensely when trying to logically structure the function that would save the registered user's credentials to an array (allowing for multiple user's), and then and additional function which would read through the array looking for a match when logging in.

I'm entirely new to Javascript, and as it stands I'm not even sure where to begin with these functions, or how I'd structure/format the array, so any help would be immensely appreciated.

```
function createUser() {}

function getUser() {}

var users = [];
```

HTML for forms

```
<div class="loginPage">
   <div name="myForm" class="form">
      <div id ="login">
         <form class="login-form" name="myForm">
            <h2>Login Page</h2>
            <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="enter username"/>
            <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="enter password"/>
            <button type="button" onclick="validateLoginForm()">login</button>
            <p class="message">Don't have an account? <a href="#register" id="register_profile">Register</a></p>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!--
   div for register back attributes, displaying form to register
   -->
<div class="registerPage">
   <div class="form">
      <div id = "register">
         <form class="register-form" name="otherForm">
            <h2>Registration Page</h2>
            <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="choose username"/>
            <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="choose password"/>
            <input name="confirmation" type="password" placeholder="re-enter password"/>
            <input name="fname" type="text" placeholder="enter first name"/>
            <input name="lname" type="text" placeholder="enter last name"/>
            <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="enter email address"/>
            <!--captcha implementation from googles re-captcha package-->
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcMZiwUAAAAAOXbpmQMVRoWUCKt2Tyf4RrhuSr_">
            </div>
            <button type="button" onclick="validateRegisterForm()">create</button>
            <p class="message">Already have an account? <a href="#login" id="login_profile">Login</a></p>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, all of the login validation, including username / password combinations will be accessible client-side?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about not clarifying that. For all intensive purposes, client-side is the intention

Comment: Then you might as well have _no_ login at all. The system you're describing is extremely easy to circumvent.

Comment: Well not exactly similar but this should be helpful to you: [Store login credentials for returning users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501444/how-to-store-login-credentials-in-localstorage)

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm really not concerned with the security aspect of things at the current point of time, more-so just trying to learn if the functionality is possible, and if so, how to go about it

Comment: Ah, fair enough! As long as you understand why you shouldn't ever do that in a real-life scenario ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do want to do this, here's the javascript ES6 approach:

```
function createUser( username, password )
{
    const user = { username, password };  //create a user object to go in the array
    users.push( user );  //put it on the end of the array
}

function getUser( username, password )
{
    //loops through each user in the array and checks the stored username and password against the one you're looking for
    return users.find( eachUser => {
        return eachUser.username === username && eachUser.password === password;
    });
}

var users = [];
```